# Как с помощью С++ работать с MS Office 2003 (Word, Excell)? Не Visual C++/ Не Borland C++

Tags: c++, windows, office, mingw, ms-word

Реализована основная часть проекта (95%).

- Язык:С++ (11); IDE: CLion 2016.2.2 CE:
- Среда: MinGW (3.21),
- Сборщик: CMake (3.6.1);

Появилась необходимость добавить модуль вывода отчетов в формате `*.doc(x)`, `*.xls(x)`, проштудировав несколько тем с форумов, и т.п. нашел варианты решения, но предназначенные для `Borland C++` 6 и `Visual C++`, а именно пользоваться стандартными борландовскими/студийными библиотеками или написать свой хедер с кучей импортов.

```
#ifdef Uses_MSO2000
// for MS Office 2000
#import "C:Program FilesMicrosoft OfficeOfficeMSO9.DLL"
#import "C:Program FilesCommon FilesMicrosoft SharedVBAVBA6VBE6EXT.OLB"
#import "C:Program FilesMicrosoft OfficeOfficeMSWORD9.OLB"
        rename("ExitWindows","_ExitWindows")
#import "C:Program FilesMicrosoft OfficeOfficeEXCEL9.OLB"
        rename("DialogBox","_DialogBox")
        rename("RGB","_RGB")
        exclude("I","IPicture")
#import "C:Program FilesCommon FilesMicrosoft SharedDAODAO360.DLL"
        rename("EOF","EndOfFile") rename("BOF","BegOfFile")
#import "C:Program FilesMicrosoft OfficeOfficeMSACC9.OLB"
#endif
```

В принципе меня бы устроил последний вариант (хэдер с импортами), однако я не нашел варианта импортов 2003 офиса, по требованию нужно иметь оба формата - 2003 и 2007, пока что преимущественно 2003. 
**Вопрос:** есть ли у кого нибудь пример, туториал, знакомая статья, можете ли поделиться опытом, как просто и без совсем лишних библиотек работать с 2003 офисом?
Вариант - переделать проект под VS или Borland - категорически не подходит. К сожалению опыт работы на `С++` не очень большой, возможно я что-то не понимаю и можно адаптировать борландовские библиотеки, или они используют какие-то стандартные библиотеки. Увы, так и не разобрался с `OLE`.

Comment: возможно это вам поможет http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34998/MS-Office-OLE-Automation-Using-C

Comment: @Alex.B, вообще уже смотрел этот проект поверхностно, он сделан в студии, сейчас попробую глянуть свежим взглядом. 
UPD: половина ресурсов содержит #include "stdafx.h", и увы из под 2013 студии не запускается. Вопрос остается открытым...

Comment: пишите вы под Windows сейчас??

Comment: Да, сейчас под windows

Comment: вот еще пара вариантов http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CppAutomateExcel-be36992e

Comment: @Alex.B ,огромное спасибо!!! Видимо взгляд замылился уже...
Да действительно codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library позволяет работать с Excel, не смотря на то что это проект под VS, немного полазив по форумам нашел как поправить ошибки и уже получил первые результаты.
В данный момент ищу что-то подобное для Word, все таки по нему идет основная отчетная работа..

Comment: а по какой причине вы используете эти ужастные пропретарные фоматы, а не pdf для формирования отчетов??

Comment: @Alex.B Потому что: 
1) это устоявшийся формат отчетов на предприятии (нововведения и усовершенствования происходят медленно или вообще не происходят)
2) основная масса пользователей, в своем распоряжении, до сих пор имеют исключительно XP SP3, MS Office 2003 (хвала админу)
3) уже куплены лицензии на Office
4) если честно pdf и самому не очень нравится (ИМХО) + неудобные редакторы, что платные что бесплатные.
5) лучше бы перешел на OpenXML (но стеснен админом и юзерами)